# How to show vertical gridlines on ngx-charts' bar-chart

Tags: javascript, angular, bar-chart

I am trying to create a basic bar-chart using ngx-charts with Angular 9. Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: picture]

Here is the code I wrote for the component:

```js
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
   [xAxis]="true"
   [yAxis]="true"
   [scheme]="singleColorScheme"
   [showGridLines]="true"
   [results]="single"
   barPadding="30"
>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

The gridlines are all horizontal and I couldn't find anything in the docs about an option to get vertical
gridlines like in my design picture. Any help?